# Does Xamarin UITest support testing iOS 11?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.uitest

I currently have a Xamarin UI Test project that was working fine until I updated to Xcode 9.6 beta. I get the below error but have found no resolution online. Nothing has changed except the version of Xcode and I am using:

System.ArgumentException : Must supply files for hashing.
Parameter name: fileInfos

return 
ConfigureApp.iOS.AppBundle(pathiOsApp).DeviceIdentifier(iPhone6).StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, i just tried, and i m running tests using Xcode_9_GM and iOS11_GM on my device.

Make sure to update your UITests packages:

> Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent.0.21.1
>
> Xamarin.UITest.2.1.1

Comment: Thanks @Rui I will update the packages and give it a go.

Comment: Does it work consistently? I get lots of failures (some successful runs) of: 
SetUp : System.Exception : Unable to determine simulator version for XXX simulator. Even though the previous test just ran and used the same simulator? 

I'm running VS(Stable) 7.3, Xamarin.iOS 11.4.0.93, Xcode 9.0.1 and using Xamarin.UITest 2.1.4

Comment: It's working fine for me, make sure you run the app in the same simulator, they also UseIdeSettings()